# Understanding this matrix transposition function in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, list, haskell

This matrix transposition function works, but I'm trying to understand its step by step execurtion and I don't get it.

```
    transpose:: [[a]]->[[a]]
    transpose ([]:_) = []
    transpose x = (map head x) : transpose (map tail x)
```

with

```
transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

it returns:

```
 [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

I don't get how the concatenation operator is working with map. It is concatenating each head of x in the same function call? How?

is this

```
(map head x)
```

creating a list of the head elements of each list?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but generally when I'm trying to wrap my head around something in Haskell, I'll spend some time playing around with it in GHCi. Try "map head" or "map tail" on a few lists of lists and you'll see for yourself how they work. If you're coming from an imperative world, maps and folds can be a little tough to grok. They're your main looping constructs -- essentially replacing "for" and "while" -- so you'll soon learn to love them.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Let's look at what the function does for your example input:

```
transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
<=>
(map head [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) : (transpose (map tail [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
<=>
[1,4,7] : (transpose [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]])
<=>
[1,4,7] : (map head [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]) : (transpose (map tail [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]))
<=>
[1,4,7] : [2,5,8] : (transpose [[3],[6],[9]])
<=>
[1,4,7] : [2,5,8] : (map head [[3],[6],[9]]) : (transpose (map tail [[3],[6],[9]]))
<=>
[1,4,7] : [2,5,8] : [3, 6, 9] : (transpose [[], [], []])
<=>
[1,4,7] : [2,5,8] : [3, 6, 9] : [] -- because transpose ([]:_) = []
<=>
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Note that the order in which I chose to reduce the terms, is not the same as the evaluation order haskell will use, but that does not change the result.

Edit: In response to your edited question:

> is this
>
> ```
> (map head x)
> ```
>
> creating a list of the head elements of each list?

Yes, it is.

Comment: were you using a debugger then?

Comment: Maybe he wrote it by himself? It is not too complex to write.

Comment: () is not creating a list. `map` which is inside () and `transpose` both create lists.

Comment: @dmindreader: `()` is Unit and it does not appear anywhere in the code. `[]` is the empty list.

Answer (score 4):

The cons operator `:` attach an object of type `a` to a list of type `[a]`. In

```
(map head x) : transpose (map tail x)
```

The LHS is a list (`a = [b]`), while the RHS is a list of list (`[a] = [[b]]`), so such a construction is valid. The result is

```
[x,y,z,...] : [[a,b,...],[d,e,...],...] = [[x,y,z,...], [a,b,...],[d,e,...],...]
```

---

In your case, `map head x` and `map tail x` splits the matrix

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

into

```
map head x = [1,4,7]
map tail x = [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]
```

(and yes, `map head x` is a list of the head elements of each list.) The 2nd part is transposed (for detail steps see [@sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578930/understanding-this-matrix-transposition-function-in-haskell/2578979#2578979)'s answer) to form

```
transpose (map tail x) = [[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

so cons-ing `[1,4,7]` to this gives

```
map head x : transpose (map tail x) =  [1,4,7] : [[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
                                    = [[1,4,7] ,  [2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

`ghci` is your friend:

```
*Main> :t map head
map head :: [[a]] -> [a]
*Main> :t map tail
map tail :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

Even if you don't understand [`map`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Amap) (a problem you'd want to correct quickly!), the types of these expressions tell much about how they work. The first is a single list taken from a list of lists, so let's feed a simple vector to it to see what happens.

You might want to write

```
*Main> map head [1,2,3]
```

but that fails to typecheck:

```
<interactive>:1:14:
    No instance for (Num [a])
      arising from the literal `3' at :1:14
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [a])
    In the expression: 3
    In the second argument of `map', namely `[1, 2, 3]'
    In the expression: map head [1, 2, 3]
```

Remember, the argument's type is a list of lists, so

```
*Main> map head [[1,2,3]]
[1]
```

Getting a bit more complex

```
*Main> map head [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
[1,4]
```

Doing the same but with [`tail`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Atail) instead of [`head`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Ahead) gives

```
*Main> map tail [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
[[2,3],[5,6]]
```

As you can see, the definition of `transpose` is repeatedly slicing off the first “row” with `map head x` and transposing the rest, which is `map tail x`.

Answer (score 2):

These things are the same:

```
map head xxs
map (\xs -> head xs) xxs
```

It's lambda-expression, which means i return the head of xs for every xs
Example:

```
   map head [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
-> map (\xs -> head xs) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
-> [head [1,2,3], head [4,5,6], head [7,8,9]]
-> [1,4,7]
```

It's simple

Answer (score 0):

By the way, this function doesn't work when given an input like `[[1,2,3], [], [1,2]]`.  However, the transpose function from `Data.List` will accept this input, and return `[[1,1], [2,2], [3]]`.

When we are calling the recursive `transpose` code, we need to get rid of the `[]`.

Comment: It would be better to put this into the comments of the actual answer; the poster is not just trying to call transpose, but rather figure out why it works.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to transpose *rectangular* arrays using `head` and `tail`, making sure that the number of columns is the same beforehand, then you can do the following:

```
rectangularTranspose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
rectangularTranspose m = rectTrans m []
  where
    rectTrans [] a = a
    rectTrans ([]:xss) a = rectTrans xss a
    rectTrans ((x:xs):xss) a = rectTrans a ((x:map head xss): rectTrans (xs:map tail xss) a)
```

---

It works for square arrays and singletons too, obviously, but I don't see much use in this when the standard implementation gives you more options.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just define your own function. I found a simpler way to implement matrix transpose in Haskell using only list comprehension. It works for a generic `m* n` matrix with non-empty elements

```
transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' xss = chop nrows [xs !! (j-1) | i <- [1..ncols], j <- take nrows [i, i+ncols ..]] 
                where nrows = length  xss
                      ncols = length(head xss) 
                      xs = concat xss 

chop :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chop _ [] = []
chop n xs = take n xs : chop n (drop n xs)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32081304)