# Get lists from where each list will contain the elements from a x position from another collection of lists

Tags: f#

basically having this:

```
[
[1;2;3];
[4;5;7];
[8;9;0];
]
```

I would like to get this (read vertically/ turn 90 degrees):

```
[
[1;4;8];
[2;5;9];
[3;7;0];
]
```

anybody knows an easy way of doing this in f# ?

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this but if you made any effort to arrive at a solution to this yourself, you should probably let people know what you've done.  Right now your question reads "plz give me the codez" whether you meant for it to or not.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I'm sorry, indeed this is what my question is, I can do this in C#, but in F# I just don't know a lot of stuff

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Technically its spelled "plz give me *teh* codez".

Comment: @ChuckNorris See "transpose" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016139/help-me-to-explain-the-f-matrix-transpose-function

Comment: @JonHarrop Thanks for teh hedz up. :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it by converting to arrays -

```
let arr = input |> List.map (List.toArray) |> List.toArray //a array of arrays
let out = Array2D.create size1 size2 (fun x y -> arr.[y].[x])
```

Comment: I was getting some strange `(int -> int -> int32) [,] =
  [[<fun:p11@269>; <fun:p11@269>; <fun:p11@269>; ...` results, changed Array2D.create to Array2D.init and I get the numbers

Comment: The first part should be shorten to `let arr = input |> array2D`.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is called **matrix transposition**.

#### PowerPack

The simplest way is using [FSharp.PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/); `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Matrix` module has `Transpose` method.

#### Simple algorithm

If you prefer your own solution, here's the one that demonstrates a good combination of short code and executing efficiency:

```
let rec transpose = function
    | (_::_)::_ as M -> List.map List.head M :: transpose (List.map List.tail M)
    | _ -> []

// use
[[1; 2; 3]; [4; 5; 6]; [7; 8; 9]]
|> transpose
|> printfn "%A"
```

#### In-place matrix transposition

Yet another approach is [in-place matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition). It has complexity of O(n), but requires mutable data.