# How do I write a ZipN-like function in F#?

Tags: f#

I want to create a function with the signature `seq<#seq<'a>> ->seq<seq<'a>>` that acts like a Zip method taking a sequence of an arbitrary number of input sequences (instead of 2 or 3 as in Zip2 and Zip3) and returning a sequence of sequences instead of tuples as a result.

That is, given the following input:

```
[[1;2;3];
 [4;5;6];
 [7;8;9]]
```

it will return the result:
    [[1;4;7];
     [2;5;8];
     [3;6;9]]

except with sequences instead of lists.

I am very new to F#, but I have created a function that does what I want, but I know it can be improved. It's not tail recursive and it seems like it could be simpler, but I don't know how yet. I also haven't found a good way to get the signature the way I want (accepting, e.g., an `int list list` as input) without a second function.

I know this could be implemented using enumerators directly, but I'm interested in doing it in a functional manner.

Here's my code:

```
let private Tail seq = Seq.skip 1 seq
let private HasLengthNoMoreThan n = Seq.skip n >> Seq.isEmpty

let rec ZipN_core = function
    | seqs when seqs |> Seq.isEmpty -> Seq.empty
    | seqs when seqs |> Seq.exists Seq.isEmpty -> Seq.empty
    | seqs ->
        let head = seqs |> Seq.map Seq.head
        let tail = seqs |> Seq.map Tail |> ZipN_core
        Seq.append (Seq.singleton head) tail

// Required to change the signature of the parameter from seq<seq<'a> to seq<#seq<'a>>
let ZipN seqs = seqs |> Seq.map (fun x -> x |> Seq.map (fun y -> y)) |> ZipN_core
```

Comment: At first sight this looks like a matrix transpose function (provided the third inner list should actually read `[3;6;9]`). Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3016139/650012) SO question?

Comment: @Anders Gustafsson You're right, it is. Thanks for the link and the typo note.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnston: It may not matter to you, but Tomas' answer in the question Anders linked to does not handle sub-lists of different lengths (same with Michael's solution below).

Comment: Sure. Typical `zip` behavior is to stop after the shortest sub-list is enumerated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```ml
let zipn items = items |> Matrix.Generic.ofSeq |> Matrix.Generic.transpose
```

Or, if you really want to write it yourself:

```ml
let zipn items = 
  let rec loop items =
    seq {
      match items with
      | [] -> ()
      | _ -> 
        match zipOne ([], []) items with
        | Some(xs, rest) -> 
          yield xs
          yield! loop rest
        | None -> ()
    }
  and zipOne (acc, rest) = function
    | [] -> Some(List.rev acc, List.rev rest)
    | []::_ -> None
    | (x::xs)::ys -> zipOne (x::acc, xs::rest) ys
  loop items
```

Comment: Thanks, the matrix solution is the shortest and clearest. Seeing alternate ways to write it out by hand is helpful too.

Comment: I'm not sure about Matrix.Generic (it was part of the now decommissioned F# power pack) but I'm pretty sure it does not perform a lazy enumeration of the sequence but loads them into memory fully. Depending on the sizes of your lists, that may be a considerable problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since this seems to be the canonical answer for writing a `zipn` in f#, I wanted to add a "pure" `seq` solution that preserves laziness and doesn't force us to load our full source sequences in memory at once like the [`Matrix.transpose`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016139/help-me-to-explain-the-f-matrix-transpose-function) function. There are scenarios where this is very important because it's a) faster and b) works with sequences that contain 100s of MBs of data!

This is probably the most un-idiomatic f# code I've written in a while but it gets the job done (and hey, why would there be sequence expressions in f# if you couldn't use them for writing procedural code in a functional language).

```
 let seqdata = seq {
  yield Seq.ofList [ 1; 2; 3 ]
  yield Seq.ofList [ 4; 5; 6 ]
  yield Seq.ofList [ 7; 8; 9 ]
}

let zipnSeq (src:seq<seq<'a>>) = seq {
  let enumerators = src |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.GetEnumerator()) |> Seq.toArray
  if (enumerators.Length > 0) then
    try 
      while(enumerators |> Array.forall(fun x -> x.MoveNext())) do 
        yield enumerators |> Array.map( fun x -> x.Current)
    finally 
      enumerators |> Array.iter (fun x -> x.Dispose())
}

zipnSeq seqdata |> Seq.toArray


val it : int [] [] = [|[|1; 4; 7|]; [|2; 5; 8|]; [|3; 6; 9|]|]
```

By the way, the traditional matrix transpose is much more terse than @Daniel's answer. Though, it requires a `list` or `LazyList` that both will eventually have the full sequence in memory.

```
let rec transpose = 
  function 
  | (_ :: _) :: _ as M -> List.map List.head M :: transpose (List.map List.tail M)
  | _ -> []
```

Comment: As it is written, the while loop spins forever on an empty input sequence because `Array.forall(...)` keeps returning true.
To ensure it copes with n=0, you could guard the try block with `if enumerators.Length > 0 then ...`

Answer (score 2):

To handle having sub-lists of different lengths, I've used option types to spot if we've run out of elements.

```
let split = function
    | []    -> None,    []
    | h::t  -> Some(h), t

let rec zipN listOfLists =
    seq { let splitted = listOfLists |> List.map split

          let anyMore = splitted |> Seq.exists (fun (f, _) -> f.IsSome)

          if anyMore then
              yield splitted |> List.map fst
              let rest = splitted |> List.map snd
              yield! rest |> zipN }
```

This would map

```
let ll = [ [ 1; 2; 3 ];
           [ 4; 5; 6 ];
           [ 7; 8; 9 ] ]
```

to

```
seq
    [seq [Some 1; Some 4; Some 7]; seq [Some 2; Some 5; Some 8];
     seq [Some 3; Some 6; Some 9]]
```

and

```
let ll = [ [ 1; 2; 3 ];
           [ 4; 5; 6 ];
           [ 7; 8 ] ]
```

to

```
seq
    [seq [Some 1; Some 4; Some 7]; seq [Some 2; Some 5; Some 8];
     seq [Some 3; Some 6; null]]
```

This takes a different approach to yours, but avoids using some of the operations that you had before (e.g. Seq.skip, Seq.append), which you should be careful with.

Comment: I forget to mention why you should be careful. When you skip items in a list, you can just repeatedly discard the head element. However, Seq.skip creates a thunk referencing the original sequence, with the instruction “skip n elements”. This has to be executed every time the sequence is enumerated, and is obviously slower. Seq.append has similar problems.

Comment: Also, this solution is tail recursive :) It handles very long input fine (e.g. ll = [ [1..100000]; [1..100000]), which would definitely cause a stack overflow otherwise!

Comment: Thanks, both for the solution and the skip/append warnings. I like this solution best of the write-it-out-by-hand options.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this answer is not very efficient, but I do like its succinctness:

```
[[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]; [7;8;9]] 
    |> Seq.collect Seq.indexed 
    |> Seq.groupBy fst 
    |> Seq.map (snd >> Seq.map snd);;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
let zipN ls =
    let rec loop (a,b) =
        match b with
        |l when List.head l = [] -> a
        |l ->
            let x1,x2 =
                (([],[]),l)
                ||> List.fold (fun acc elem ->
                    match acc,elem with
                    |(ah,at),eh::et -> ah@[eh],at@[et]
                    |_ -> acc)
            loop (a@[x1],x2)
    loop ([],ls)
```