# F# Matrix Multiplication

Tags: f#, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiply two matrices.

I'm using transpose taken from this post: [Help me to explain the F# Matrix transpose function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016139/help-me-to-explain-the-f-matrix-transpose-function)

```
let rec transpose = function
| (_::_)::_ as M -> List.map List.head M :: transpose (List.map List.tail M)
| _ -> []
```

I'm also using innerMult which multiplies every element of a two lists and then adds them.

```
let rec innerMult u v =
match u, v with 
| [x], [y] -> x*y     | u'::u, v'::v -> u'*v' + inner u v
```

So using these two functions I want will try to multiply rows by columns. Of course I assume both matrices meet the conditions for multiplication to happen. That is, rows must equal columns.

Matrix multiplication code:

```
let multiply (xs, ys) = 
let tl = transpose ys in 
    let rec mMult xs = 
    match xs, tl with
    | x::xs, t::tl -> inner x t
  mMult xs;;
```

> Test: multiply ([[1;2;3];[4;5;6]], [[0;1];[3;2];[1;2]]);; Output: >
>   val it : int = 9

At the moment it is missing recursion or List.map so that it actually does the matrix multiplication. I just don't see how to solve this.

Comment: you might want to use math.net if you do anything requiring decent perf. this has an entry cost, however. technical computing has its little rules..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this ought to work:

```
let multiply xs ys =
    [for row in xs ->
         [for col in transpose ys -> inner row col]]
```

Comment: Can I do it without the for loops?

Comment: Well, I think it's clearest with for loops, but you can always just replace `[for variable in someList -> body]` with `someList |> List.map (fun variable -> body)` if you prefer.

Comment: Something like this? xs |> List.map (transpose ys -> (inner xs ys))

Comment: No, you need to replace both list comprehensions: `let multiply xs ys = xs |> List.map (fun row -> transpose ys |> List.map (fun col -> inner row col))`.

Comment: Can you explain the code. Especially how |> affects List.map? I will deeply appreciate it.

Comment: `|>` isn't strictly necessary, but can help type inference in some circumstances.  `x |> f` has the same result as `f x`, so you can just write `let multiply xs ys = List.map (fun row -> List.map (fun col -> inner row col) (transpose ys)) xs`.

Comment: what is the function for "inner" ?

Comment: @AlexV - I just copied that from the definition of `multiply` in the question, but it should be the same as `innerMult`.