# How to transpose a matrix?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I am new at F#.

I want to transpose a matrix, I can do this with loops like in any other language, But I want to do it with out loops.

My Matrix Declaration :

```
let BuildEmptyBord:BordCell[][]=[|for i in 1..3->[|for i in 1..3->BordCell.Empty|]|]
```

So please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help me to explain the F# Matrix transpose function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016139/help-me-to-explain-the-f-matrix-transpose-function)

Comment: But this is list matrix, my matrix is Array matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matrix as jagged array you can use the `Array.init` function and then re-create the matrix with the dimensions swapped, like this:

```
let transpose (matrix:_ [][]) =
    if matrix.Length = 0 then failwith "Invalid matrix"  
    Array.init matrix.[0].Length (fun i -> 
        Array.init matrix.Length (fun j -> 
            matrix.[j].[i]))
```

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.