# F#, implement fold3, fold4, fold_n

Tags: f#

I am interested to implement fold3, fold4 etc., similar to List.fold and List.fold2. e.g.

```
// TESTCASE
let polynomial (x:double) a b c = a*x + b*x*x + c*x*x*x
let A = [2.0; 3.0; 4.0; 5.0]
let B = [1.5; 1.0; 0.5; 0.2]
let C = [0.8; 0.01; 0.001; 0.0001]

let result = fold3 polynomial 0.7 A B C
// 2.0 * (0.7   ) + 1.5 * (0.7   )^2 + 0.8    * (0.7   )^3 -> 2.4094
// 3.0 * (2.4094) + 1.0 * (2.4094)^2 + 0.01   * (2.4094)^3 -> 13.173
// 4.0 * (13.173) + 0.5 * (13.173)^2 + 0.001  * (13.173)^3 -> 141.75
// 5.0 * (141.75) + 0.2 * (141.75)^2 + 0.0001 * (141.75)^3 -> 5011.964
//
// Output: result = 5011.964
```

My first method is grouping the 3 lists A, B, C, into a list of tuples, and then apply list.fold

```
let fold3 f x A B C =
    List.map3 (fun a b c -> (a,b,c)) A B C
       |> List.fold (fun acc (a,b,c) -> f acc a b c) x

// e.g. creates [(2.0,1.5,0.8);  (3.0,1.0,0.01); ......]
```

My second method is to declare a mutable data, and use List.map3

```
let mutable result = 0.7
List.map3 (fun a b c ->
               result <- polynomial result a b c  // Change mutable data
               // Output intermediate data
               result) A B C
// Output from List.map3: [2.4094; 13.17327905; 141.7467853; 5011.963942]
// result mutable: 5011.963942
```

I would like to know if there are other ways to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: this is not really a good question for SO as it is open ended.

Answer (score 6):

For `fold3`, you could just do `zip3` and then `fold`:

```
let polynomial (x:double) (a, b, c) = a*x + b*x*x + c*x*x*x
List.zip3 A B C |> List.fold polynomial 0.7
```

---

But if you want this for the general case, then you need what we call *"applicative functors"*.

First, imagine you have a list of functions and a list of values. Let's assume for now they're of the same size:

```
let fs = [ (fun x -> x+1); (fun x -> x+2); (fun x -> x+3) ]
let xs = [3;5;7]
```

And what you'd like to do (only natural) is to apply each function to each value. This is easily done with `List.map2`:

```
let apply fs xs = List.map2 (fun f x -> f x) fs xs

apply fs xs  // Result = [4;7;10]
```

This operation "apply" is why these are called "applicative functors". Not just any ol' functors, but *applicative* ones. (the reason for why they're "functors" is a tad more complicated)

So far so good. But wait! What if each function in my list of functions returned another function?

```
let f1s = [ (fun x -> fun y -> x+y); (fun x -> fun y -> x-y); (fun x -> fun y -> x*y) ]
```

Or, if I remember that `fun x -> fun y -> ...` can be written in the short form of `fun x y -> ...`

```
let f1s = [ (fun x y -> x+y); (fun x y -> x-y); (fun x y -> x*y) ]
```

What if I `apply` such list of functions to my values? Well, naturally, I'll get another list of functions:

```
let f2s = apply f1s xs
// f2s = [ (fun y -> 3+y); (fun y -> 5+y); (fun y -> 7+y) ]
```

Hey, here's an idea! Since `f2s` is *also* a list of functions, can I apply it again? Well of course I can!

```
let ys = [1;2;3]
apply f2s ys  // Result: [4;7;10]
```

Wait, what? What just happened?
I first applied the first list of functions to `xs`, and got another list of functions as a result. And then I applied that result to `ys`, and got a list of numbers.
We could rewrite that without intermediate variable `f2s`:

```
let f1s = [ (fun x y -> x+y); (fun x y -> x-y); (fun x y -> x*y) ]
let xs = [3;5;7]
let ys = [1;2;3]
apply (apply f1s xs) ys  // Result: [4;7;10]
```

For extra convenience, this operation `apply` is usually expressed as an operator:

```
let (<*>) = apply
f1s <*> xs <*> ys
```

See what I did there? With this operator, it now looks very similar to just calling the function with two arguments. Neat.

But wait. What about our original task? In the original requirements we don't have a list of functions, we only have one single function.
Well, that can be easily fixed with another operation, let's call it "apply first". This operation will take a single function (not a list) plus a list of values, and apply this function to each value in the list:

```
let applyFirst f xs = List.map f xs
```

Oh, wait. That's just `map`. Silly me :-)
For extra convenience, this operation is usually also given an operator name:

```
let (<|>) = List.map
```

And now, I can do things like this:

```
let f x y = x + y
let xs = [3;5;7]
let ys = [1;2;3]
f <|> xs <*> ys  // Result: [4;7;10]
```

Or this:

```
let f x y z = (x + y)*z
let xs = [3;5;7]
let ys = [1;2;3]
let zs = [1;-1;100]
f <|> xs <*> ys <*> zs  // Result: [4;-7;1000]
```

Neat! I made it so I can apply arbitrary functions to lists of arguments at once!

Now, finally, you can apply this to your original problem:

```
let polynomial a b c (x:double) = a*x + b*x*x + c*x*x*x
let A = [2.0; 3.0; 4.0; 5.0]
let B = [1.5; 1.0; 0.5; 0.2]
let C = [0.8; 0.01; 0.001; 0.0001]

let ps = polynomial <|> A <*> B <*> C
let result = ps |> List.fold (fun x f -> f x) 0.7
```

The list `ps` consists of `polynomial` instances that are partially applied to corresponding elements of `A`, `B`, and `C`, and still expecting the final argument `x`. And on the next line, I simply fold over this list of functions, applying each of them to the result of the previous.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the implementation for ideas:

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs

```
  let fold<'T,'State> (f : 'State -> 'T -> 'State) (acc: 'State) (array:'T[]) =
        checkNonNull "array" array
        let f = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_,_,_>.Adapt(f)
        let mutable state = acc             
        for i = 0 to array.Length-1 do 
            state <- f.Invoke(state,array.[i])
        state
```

here's a few implementations for you:

```
let fold2<'a,'b,'State> (f : 'State -> 'a -> 'b -> 'State) (acc: 'State) (a:'a array) (b:'b array) =
  let mutable state = acc    
  Array.iter2 (fun x y->state<-f state x y) a b
  state

let iter3 f (a: 'a[]) (b: 'b[]) (c: 'c[]) = 
  let f = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_,_,_,_>.Adapt(f)
  if a.Length <> b.Length || a.Length <> c.Length then failwithf "length"
  for i = 0 to a.Length-1 do 
    f.Invoke(a.[i], b.[i], c.[i])

let altIter3 f (a: 'a[]) (b: 'b[]) (c: 'c[]) = 
  if a.Length <> b.Length || a.Length <> c.Length then failwithf "length"
  for i = 0 to a.Length-1 do 
    f (a.[i]) (b.[i]) (c.[i])

let fold3<'a,'b,'State> (f : 'State -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'State) (acc: 'State) (a:'a array) (b:'b array) (c:'c array) =
  let mutable state = acc    
  iter3 (fun x y z->state<-f state x y z) a b c
  state
```

NB. we don't have an iter3, so, implement that. OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc only allow up to 5 (or is it 7?) params. There are a finite number of type slots available. It makes sense. You can go higher than this, of course, without using the OptimizedClosures stuff.

... anyway, generally, you don't want to be iterating too many lists / arrays / sequences at once. So I'd caution against going too high.

... the better way forward in such cases may be to construct a record or tuple from said lists / arrays, first. Then, you can just use map and iter, which are already baked in. This is what zip / zip3 are all about (see: "(array1.[i],array2.[i],array3.[i])")

```
    let zip3 (array1: _[]) (array2: _[]) (array3: _[]) = 
        checkNonNull "array1" array1
        checkNonNull "array2" array2
        checkNonNull "array3" array3
        let len1 = array1.Length
        if len1 <> array2.Length || len1 <> array3.Length then invalidArg3ArraysDifferent "array1" "array2" "array3" len1 array2.Length array3.Length
        let res = Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array.zeroCreateUnchecked len1 
        for i = 0 to res.Length-1 do 
            res.[i] <- (array1.[i],array2.[i],array3.[i])
        res
```

I'm working with arrays at the moment, so my solution pertained to those. Sorry about that. Here's a recursive version for lists.

```
let fold3 f acc a b c =
  let mutable state = acc
  let rec fold3 f a b c =
    match a,b,c with
    | [],[],[] -> ()
    | [],_,_
    | _,[],_
    | _,_,[] -> failwith "length"
    | ahead::atail, bhead::btail, chead::ctail -> 
        state <- f state ahead bhead chead
        fold3 f atail btail ctail
    fold3 f a b c
```

i.e. we define a recursive function within a function which acts upon/mutates/changes the outer scoped mutable *acc* variable (a closure in functional speak). Finally, this gets returned.

It's pretty cool how much type information gets inferred about these functions. In the array examples above, mostly I was explicit with 'a 'b 'c. This time, we let type inference kick in. It knows we're dealing with lists from the **::** operator. That's kind of neat.

NB. the compiler will *probably* unwind this tail-recursive approach so that it is just a loop behind-the-scenes. Generally, get a correct answer before optimising. Just mentioning this, though, as food for later thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think the existing answers provide great options if you want to generalize folding, which was your original question. However, if I simply wanted to call the `polynomial` function on inputs specified in `A`, `B` and `C`, then I would probably do not want to introduce fairly complex constructs like applicative functors with fancy operators to my code base.

The problem becomes a lot easier if you transpose the input data, so that rather than having a list `[A; B; C]` with lists for individual variables, you have a transposed list with inputs for calculating each polynomial. To do this, we'll need the [transpose function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016139/help-me-to-explain-the-f-matrix-transpose-function):

```
let rec transpose = function
  | (_::_)::_ as M -> List.map List.head M :: transpose (List.map List.tail M)
  | _ -> []
```

Now you can create a list with inputs, transpose it and calculate all polynomials simply using `List.map`:

```
transpose [A; B; C]
|> List.map (function 
  | [a; b; c] -> polynomial 0.7 a b c
  | _ -> failwith "wrong number of arguments")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem. Few are mentioned like first `zip3` all three list, then run over it. Using Applicate Functors like Fyodor Soikin describes means you can turn any function with any amount of arguments into a function that expects list instead of single arguments. This is a good general solution that works with any numbers of lists.

While this is a general good idea, i'm sometimes shocked that so few use more low-level tools. In this case it is a good idea to use recursion and learn more about recursion.

Recursion here is the right-tool because we have immutable data-types. But you could consider how you would implement it with mutable lists and looping first, if that helps. The steps would be:

1. You loop over an index from 0 to the amount of elements in the lists.
2. You check if every list has an element for the index
3. If every list has an element then you pass this to your "folder" function
4. If at least one list don't have an element, then you abort the loop

The recursive version works exactly the same. Only that you don't use an index to access the elements. You would chop of the first element from every list and then recurse on the remaining list.

Otherwise `List.isEmpty` is the function to check if a List is empty. You can chop off the first element with `List.head` and you get the remaining list with the first element removed by `List.tail`. This way you can just write:

```
let rec fold3 f acc l1 l2 l3 =
    let h = List.head
    let t = List.tail
    let empty = List.isEmpty

    if   (empty l1) || (empty l2) && (empty l3)
    then acc
    else fold3 f (f acc (h l1) (h l2) (h l3)) (t l1) (t l2) (t l3)
```

The `if` line checks if every list has at least one element. If that is true
it executes: `f acc (h l1) (h l2) (h l3)`. So it executes `f` and passes it the first element of every list as an argument. The result is the new accumulator of
the next `fold3` call.

Now that you worked on the first element of every list, you must chop off the first element of every list, and continue with the remaining lists. You achieve that with `List.tail` or in the above example `(t l1) (t l2) (t l3)`. Those are the next remaining lists for the next `fold3` call.

Creating a `fold4`, `fold5`, `fold6` and so on isn't really hard, and I think it is self-explanatory. My general advice is to learn a little bit more about recursion and try to write recursive List functions without Pattern Matching. Pattern Matching is not always easier.

Some code examples:

```
fold3 (fun acc x y z -> x + y + z :: acc)   [] [1;2;3] [10;20;30] [100;200;300] // [333;222;111]
fold3 (fun acc x y z -> x :: y :: z :: acc) [] [1;2;3] [10;20;30] [100;200;300] // [3; 30; 300; 2; 20; 200; 1; 10; 100]
```